# Update SQL Server data from HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, ajax

I have the following table:

```
<table id="skuTable" role="grid">
    <thead>
        <th class="skuRow">Orden</th>
        <th>Fecha Fab.</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Norden</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Metros</th>
        <th>Tiempo</th>
        <th>Fecha Ent.</th>
        <th>Operario</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Editar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

I get the data from the machine 41

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  Orden, FFab, N_Orden=Ordenes.OF_N_Orden, Color, Client, Metros, Tiempo, FEnt,Operario
        FROM ((
                Ordenes INNER JOIN VCLIENTE ON VCLIENTE.Clie_codigo = Ordenes.OF_Cod_Cli
            ) INNER JOIN ARTITTEC ON ARTITTEC.Tec_codigo = Ordenes.OF_Cod_Art
        ) 
        INNER JOIN VTiempos ON  VTiempos.Of_n_orden= Ordenes.OF_N_Orden 
            AND Vtiempos.OF_LIN =Ordenes.OF_Lin
        ORDER BY Orden asc, Fecha asc";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
I write the data in the columns

      <td class="orden" id="orden-<?= intval($row['Orden']) ?>"><?php echo $row['Orden'] ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['FFab']; ?></td>
        <td class="norden" align="center" id="norden-<?= intval($row['N_Orden']) ?>"><?php echo $row['N_Orden']; ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Color']; ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Client']; ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Metros']; ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Tiempo']; ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['FEnt']; ?></td>
        <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Operario']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>

        </tr></b></font>
        <?php { ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget k-floatwrap" data-role="pager">
    <span class="k-pager-info k-label"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript for the Edit function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#skuTable .edit", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds   = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
        $this.val('Save');
        if ($this.id !== '.orden') {
            tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
        }
    }
    else {
        var isValid = true;
        var errors  = '';
        $('#myDialogBox').empty();
        var elements = tds;
        if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
            elements = tds.find('input');
        }
        var dict = {};
        elements.each(function (index, element) {
            var type  = $(this).attr('class');
            var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
            console.log(type);
            // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
            switch (type) {
                case "norden":
                    dict["N_Orden"] = value;
                    break;
                case "orden":
                    dict["Orden"] = value;
                    break;
            }
        })
        if (isValid) {
            console.log(dict);
            $this.val('Edit');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST", url: "update.php", data: dict
            });

            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (JSON.parse(response) == true) {
                    console.log("row updated");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("row failed to updated");
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });

            // Callback handler that will be called on failure
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Log the error to the console
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
            });

            // Callback handler that will be called regardless
            // if the request failed or succeeded
            request.always(function () {

            });
        }
        else {
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
});
```

Script Update.php:

```
<?php
$Orden  = $_POST['Orden'];
$NOrden = $_POST['NOrden'];
$host   = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$dbName = "xxxxx";
$dbUser = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbPass = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$pdo    = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=" . $host . ";Database=" . $dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$sql    = "UPDATE Ordenes SET OF_OrdenOFs = '$Orden' WHERE OF_N_Orden = '$NOrden'";
$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
//$stmt->bindValue('[:SKU Group]', $SKU);
//$stmt->bindValue(':Group_ID', $Group_ID)  
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo json_encode($result);
if (!$result) {
    echo json_encode(sqlsrv_errors());
}
?>
```

Currently when I press the **edit** button, it lets me edit the **Order** field and giving save apparently saves it for me. But when refreshing the page, the records appear blank (that is, if there was no data in the database, it continues to leave it blank and if there was a data before, not only does it not change it, but it also deletes it).

What can I be failing at?

Comment: You need to use parameters in your `UPDATE` statement. What are the actual values of `$Orden` and `$NOrden` variables? Thanks.

Comment: I do not know that I have the wrong thing or that I have to modify so that it passes the update.php the two data of each row when giving it to save

Answer (score 0):

During your JavaScript update call you seem to be setting the value you want to update to `dict["N_Orden"]`. However, in your `Update.php` you seem to be wanting the value of `$_POST['NOrden']` which I don't believe is defined?

Comment: How should I define them in the table or script then?